# Can not install a program that requires libglib

Tags: drivers, software-center, software-installation, intel

*Edit: I think the problem was simple incompatibility between my version of Ubuntu and the one the software required. You can lock this topic. Thanks to Nattgew.*

---

You see, I need to install certain Intel graphic drivers for which I tried to download the *"Linux Intel graphic driver Installer"* (http://bit.ly/1kbIcKm).

However, when Ubuntu Software Center opens the *.deb* file it tells that there is a dependency issue because it needs libglib >=2.37.3 version.

I have tried to do what I always do in these cases and use the console to update the libraries with *"sudo apt-get install libglib-2.0"*, but it tells me libglib is already up to date.
While I am not good at all with these things, I evena tried to install it by hand. I went to linuxFromScratch (http://bit.ly/1hFY9u7) , downloaded the libglib2.40.0 library and installed it manually. It apparently worked because the file appears in *usr/lib/pkgconfig*.

The thing is that I am STILL getting the message of "dependency issue". Do you know what could be the problem? Maybe Ubuntu Software Center is not detecting the correct library?

Comment: Did you make sure to download the 32 or 64-bit version to match what your computer is running?

Comment: You can easily install it by `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel`. isn`t it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use a .deb file to install, i.e. when you do a `make install` like the instructions you linked, then the Ubuntu software system (apt) knows nothing about you installing that library. So as far as Ubuntu Software Center is concerned, the `libglib` package is still at the Ubuntu version. You have two options to resolve this:

1. Force the .deb file to install, ignoring the dependency issue. Hopefully the manual library install worked and the program will function properly.

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i --force-depends *.deb
   ```

   You can replace the `*.deb` with the specific package file name, otherwise it matches all .deb files in the directory.
2. Upgrade Ubuntu. The latest two Ubuntu versions (13.10 and 14.04) have versions of `libglib-2.0` that meet the requirements (>=2.37.3). You can check the versions here: 
   http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libglib2.0-0

Comment: My Ubuntu-desktop is already updated at the latest version of 14.04, so according to your link it already had libglib-2.0(>=2.37.3) from the very begging... which means I have NO idea what's going wrong here. I guess I will just try to force-install it and see what happens. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: It turns out I had Ubuntu 13.04 not 14.04. I guess I only have to update my version of Ubuntu and things will work out by themselves. If I had enough points to give you a thumbs up I would. Thank you so VERY  much, you've been really helpful. :D